# Fallo al crear .exe desde .py con pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.7, pyinstaller

al crear el .exe con pyinstaller de mi aplicación .py no me da ningún error pero al ejecutar el .exe este no funciona. 
Me aparece un ventana con el siguiente error: Failed to execute script "nombre_script". 
He eliminado las imágenes que utilizaba con Tkinter pero el problema permanece. Alguien sabe como podría solucionar este problema? 
El script funciona correctamente pero necesito el .exe para el uso de otros compañeros en sus ordenadores.
Utilizo otro script para comunicar con una base de datos Mysql y trabajar los datos leídos de un código de barras, pero el ejecutable no funciona aunque solo intente crear el .exe para probar la parte gráfica creada con Tkinter.

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    from DB_SN import *

    def value_SN(Event):

        Serial = valor_SN(barcode.get())
        text_Sn.set(Serial[0])                     # Le asignamos el valor de la variable 'Serial'
        text_Kr.set(Serial[1])                      # Le asignamos el valor de la variable 'K_ref'
        text_Cr.set(Serial[2])                      # Le asignamos el valor de la variable 'C_ref'
        text_HW.set(Serial[3])                      # Le asignamos el valor de la variable 'HW_ref'
        text_SW.set(Serial[4])                      # Le asignamos el valor de la variable 'SW_ref'
        text_F.set(Serial[5])
        SN_Entry.delete(0, 'end')   
        SN_Entry.get()   


   root = Tk()
   root.geometry('1400x700')
   root.configure(bg = 'grey')   

   miFrame=Frame(root, width="700", height="700")                     # Creamos el frmae y le asignamos dimensiones

   miFrame.pack(fill="both", expand = "True")                          # Hacemos que sea reescalable y quede centrado en x e y

   miFrame.config(cursor="pirate")                                     # Cambiamos el puntero del ratón por una calavera pirata

   SN_Label = Label(miFrame, text="Serial Number", font=("Arial", 18)) # Creamos la etiqueta del Serial Number
   SN_Label.grid(row=1,column=0, pady=20, padx=20)                     # La ubicamos dentro del Frame

   Sn_s_Label = Label(miFrame, text="SN:", font=("Arial", 14))        
   #Creamos la etiqueta del SN
   Sn_s_Label.grid(row=3,column=0, pady=20, padx=20)

   text_Sn = StringVar()   
   Sn_r_Label = Label(miFrame, font=("Arial", 14),textvariable=text_Sn)                     
   # Creamos la etiqueta para mostrar el valor del Sn
   Sn_r_Label.grid(row=3,column=1, pady=20, padx=20)

   K_Label = Label(miFrame, text="reference:", font=("Arial", 14))  # Creamos la etiqueta de reference
   K_Label.grid(row=4,column=0, pady=20, padx=20)

   text_Kr = StringVar()  
   K_r_Label = Label(miFrame, font=("Arial", 14),textvariable=text_Kr)                          
   # Creamos la etiqueta para mostrar el valor de reference
   K_r_Label.grid(row=4,column=1, pady=20, padx=20)

   C_Label = Label(miFrame, text="Customer reference:", font=("Arial", 14))  
   # Creamos la etiqueta de Customer reference
   C_Label.grid(row=5,column=0, pady=20, padx=20)

   text_Cr = StringVar()
   C_r_Label = Label(miFrame, font=("Arial", 14),textvariable=text_Cr)                          # Creamos la etiqueta para mostrar el valor de Customer reference
   C_r_Label.grid(row=5,column=1, pady=20, padx=20)

   HW_Label = Label(miFrame, text="HW:", font=("Arial", 14))               # Creamos la etiqueta de HW
   HW_Label.grid(row=4,column=2, pady=20, padx=20)

   text_HW = StringVar()
   HW_r_Label = Label(miFrame, font=("Arial", 14),textvariable=text_HW)                         
   # Creamos la etiqueta para mostrar el valor de HW
   HW_r_Label.grid(row=4,column=3, pady=20, padx=20)

   SW_Label = Label(miFrame, text="SW:", font=("Arial", 14))                 
   # Creamos la etiqueta de SW
   SW_Label.grid(row=5,column=2, pady=20, padx=20)

   text_SW = StringVar()
   SW_r_Label = Label(miFrame, font=("Arial", 14),textvariable=text_SW)                         
   # Creamos la etiqueta para mostrar el valor de SW
   SW_r_Label.grid(row=5,column=3, pady=20, padx=20)

   F_Label = Label(miFrame, text="Failure", font=("Arial", 18))            # 
   Creamos la etiqueta de Fail
   F_Label.grid(row=6,column=0, pady=20, padx=20)

   text_F = StringVar()
   F_r_Label = Label(miFrame, font=("Arial", 18),textvariable=text_F)                       
   # Creamos la etiqueta para mostrar el valor de Fail
   F_r_Label.grid(row=6,column=1, pady=20, padx=20,columnspan=10)


   barcode=StringVar()

   # Creamos Entry para leer con la pistola y se active la busqueda con el intro final de la lectura
   SN_Entry = Entry(miFrame, width=70, textvariable=barcode)
   SN_Entry.grid(row=1,column=1, pady=20, padx=20, columnspan=2)
   SN_Entry.focus()
   SN_Entry.bind('<Key-Return>', value_SN)

   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Necesitas un agregar el bloque `if __name__ == '__main__': root.mainloop()`

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo crearlo con la aplicacion de `scipy`, te dejo el link para que lo descargues: https://www.scipy.org/. es muy facil de utilizar y puedes insetrar imagenes, etc.